# Slack api request serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, slack-api

Somehow the model is not deserialized, but if change SlackResponse class to  string, then inside will be raw json, as it may have settings from JSON.Net what would she normally deserializable?

Input data

> payload={\"type\":\"message_action\",\"token\":\"000\",\"action_ts\":\"000\",\"team\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"domain\":\"000\"},\"user\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"name\":\"000\"},\"channel\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"name\":\"000\"},\"callback_id\":\"rm_create\",\"trigger_id\":\"000\",\"message_ts\":\"000\",\"message\":{\"bot_id\":\"000\",\"type\":\"message\",\"text\":\"000\",\"user\":\"000\",\"ts\":\"000\",\"team\":\"000\"},\"response_url\":\"000\"}

In C# created class

```
public partial class SlackResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("action_ts")]
    public string ActionTs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("team")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public Channel User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("callback_id")]
    public string CallbackId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trigger_id")]
    public string TriggerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message_ts")]
    public string MessageTs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public Message Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response_url")]
    public Uri ResponseUrl { get; set; }
}

public partial class Channel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("client_msg_id")]
    public Guid ClientMsgId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ts")]
    public string Ts { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("team")]
    public string Team { get; set; }
}

public partial class Team
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

And controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Get([FromForm(Name = "payload")] SlackResponse payload)
{
}
```

Comment: @John

if use string as an input parameter to the method, then string will be :
`payload={\"type\":\"message_action\",\"token\":\"000\",\"action_ts\":\"000\",\"team\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"domain\":\"000\"},\"user\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"name\":\"000\"},\"channel\":{\"id\":\"000\",\"name\":\"000\"},\"callback_id\":\"rm_create\",\"trigger_id\":\"000\",\"message_ts\":\"000\",\"message\":{\"bot_id\":\"000\",\"type\":\"message\",\"text\":\"000\",\"user\":\"000\",\"ts\":\"000\",\"team\":\"000\"},\"response_url\":\"000\"}`

Comment: The string contains the text `payload=`?

Comment: oops.
forgot to delete when copied, not the string does not contain `payload=`

Comment: Then you'll probably want `[FromBody]`, not `[FromForm]`, since you're receiving JSON and not form-encoded data.

Comment: This I tried in the beginning, if change to FromBody you get 415 code

Comment: Does the request you're making to this endpoint include an appropriate `Content-Type` header (i.e. `application/json`)?

Comment: No, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/b5JjGWk

Comment: Does this request originate from Slack's API? If so, that's very weird. They've encoded JSON and then supplied it as a form field in a form post. Given the actual data you're receiving, I'm inclined to think that your solution is best.

Comment: Yes, this data comes from the Slack API.
Totally agree with you,very strange API.
Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in asp.net core [FromForm is not support serialization](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4868#issuecomment-355974439), the simplest solution is this

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Get([FromForm(Name ="payload")] string jsonString)
{
    var payload= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackResponse>(jsonString);
}
```